# R Error in gmap function: document is empty

Tags: r

I wanted to use R dismo package dealing with GIS data, but got blocked at the first step:

```
g <- gmap("Australia")
```

There are errors no matter what country I type:

```
Error : 1: Document is empty
Error in .geocode(xx$place, oneRecord = oneRecord, extent = extent,
progress = progress) : 
  object 'doc' not found
```

I can use both google earth and google map. 
Does anyone know how to solve it? Thank you for everyone.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. `library(dismo); g <- gmap("Australia"); plot(g)` works fine on my Mac with `dismo_1.1-4`, `R_3.4.0`.

Comment: I use dismo_1.1-4 and R_3.5.1, but they have the same error on both MacOS and Windows.